# Align <li> elements at the bottom of <ul>

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I created realtime chat boxes

There is a "chat" `<ul>` element bar at the bottom of the page, on which I put many chatBoxes `<li>`. These chatboxes can be minimized. Nothing really fancy, it's what many people do, including facebook.

The matter is that when one chatbox is minimized and another is not, then the minimized chat does not stick to the bottom of the page: it on the middle of the page, aligned to the  top of the other non-minimized chat.

Here is a JsFiddle that shows the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/k8UTJ/1/

Please can someone edit this JsFiddle to show me that we can align the "User2" chat bar (minimized) to the bottom of the page?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was `float:right` in your `.chatBox` . [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/k8UTJ/10/)

Comment: thanks but it is not the problem actually. The problem is not the space between the item and the bottom of the page, but the fact that the black bar with `User 2` should be aligned with the text input of the 2nd chat. I have edited my post, using your JsFiddle so that other readers won't be confused

Comment: @SebastienLorber : i hope, now m getting your exact issue.. please check the updated fiddle.

Comment: thanks @Era, it's fine but how do I get the User2 on the left instead of the right? I'd rather not change the `li` order and in your exemple the order was reversed :)

Comment: @Sebastien Lorber : then we need have to use some trick with js. see updated fiddle.